# Issue on build.gradle and custom task

Tags: android, gradle, fastlane

In order to manage my build pipeline for Android app, I have added a task and custom functions in `build.gradle` to I can trigger an increment of the build version.

For now, I have this file `version.properties` in the root project dir and I have added at the end of the `build.gradle` in the project dir, the below code:

Version.properties

```
major = 0
minor = 4
patch = 0
build = 1
```

build.gradle

```
def readVersion() {
    def versionFile = new File(project.rootDir, 'version.properties')
    def version = new Properties()
    def stream

    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(versionFile)
        version.load(stream)
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ignore) {
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) stream.close()
    }

    if(!version['major']) version ['major'] = "0"
    if(!version['minor']) version ['minor'] = "0"
    if(!version['patch']) version ['patch'] = "0"
    if(!version['build']) version ['build'] = "0"

    return version
}

def getVersionCode() {
    def version = readVersion()
    def major = version['major']
    def minor = version['minor']
    def patch = version['patch']
    def build = version['build']

    return major * 1000000 + minor * 10000 + patch * 100 + build
}

def getVersionName() {
    def version = readVersion()
    return "v${version['major']}" +
            ".${version['minor']}" +
            ".${version['patch']}" +
            "-rc${version['build']}"
}

def incrementBuildNumber() {
    def versionFile = new File(project.rootDir, 'version.properties')
    def version = new Properties()

    def build = version['build']
    build = build+1
    version['build'] = build.toString

    def stream = new FileOutputStream(versionFile)
    try {
        version.store(stream, null)
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) stream.close()
    }
    //return build
}

task doBuildNumberIncrement() {
    incrementBuildNumber()
}
```

in the same build.gradle, I have:

```
ext {

    //Version
    versionCode = getVersionCode()
    versionName = getVersionName()
```

and I have added in the Fastfile the lane:

```
    desc "Build and release on firebase"
    lane :build_and_release_to_firebase do
        increment_version()
        develop_build(flavor: "MyFlavor")


   desc "Manage build version"
    lane :increment_version do
      gradle(task: "doBuildNumberIncrement")
    end
```

When I running locally the command with the cmd line `fastlane build_and_release_to_firebase` I am having the error below:

```
* Where:
Build file '/MyProject/build.gradle' line: 155
```

the line 155 is when I do `build = build+1` in the `incrementBuildNumber`

Any idea why ? I try `builld++` but same issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

because `version` object is empty and you'll get NullPointerException (null+1) at 155 because of that.

you can call `readVersion()` function that you wrote before to create the version object ( or load from FileInputStream by using versionFile)

solution as below

```
  def incrementBuildNumber() {
    
        def versionFile = new File(project.rootDir, 'version.properties')
        def version = readVersion()
    
        def build = version['build']
        build = build + 1
        version['build'] = build.toString()
    
        def stream = new FileOutputStream(versionFile)
        try {
            version.store(stream, null)
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) stream.close()
        }
        //return build
    }
```